# How extract part of an URL in PHP to remove specific part?

Tags: php, regex, url

So, I have this URL in a string:

```
http://www.domain.com/something/interesting_part/?somevars&othervars
```

in PHP, how I can get rid of all but `interesting_part`?

Comment: You should mark right answer in each of your questions, if there's any.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

...

```
$url = 'http://www.domain.com/something/interesting_part/?somevars&othervars';
$parts = explode('/', $url);
echo $parts[4];
```

**Output:**

```
interesting_part
```

Comment: I was just writing this as you posted :D

Comment: If 'something' does not have '/' inside then it's the best way to achieve it.

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://www.domain.com/something/interesting_part/?somevars&othervars';

preg_match('`/([^/]+)/[^/]*$`', $url, $m);
echo $m[1];
```

Comment: I don't know why somebody did "-1" on this. Its equivalent to exploding the thing. I pushed it back to 0 :)

Comment: People see regular expressions and they stab their author.

Answer (score 5):

You should use [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to do operations with URL. First parse it, then do changes you desire, using, for example, explode, then put it back together.

```
$uri = "http://www.domain.com/something/interesting_part/?somevars&othervars";
$uri_parts = parse_url( $uri );

/*
you should get:
 array(4) {
  ["scheme"]=>
  string(4) "http"
  ["host"]=>
  string(14) "www.domain.com"
  ["path"]=>
  string(28) "/something/interesting_part/"
  ["query"]=>
  string(18) "somevars&othervars"
}
*/

...

// whatever regex or explode (regex seems to be a better idea now)
// used on $uri_parts[ "path" ]

...

$new_uri = $uri_parts[ "scheme" ] + $uri_parts[ "host" ] ... + $new_path ...
```

Answer (score 2):

If the interesting part is always last part of path:

```
echo basename(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH));
```

[+] please note that this will only work without `index.php` or any other file name before `?`. This one will work for both cases:

```
$path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
echo  ($path[strlen($path)-1] == '/') ? basename($path) : basename(dirname($path));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is example using [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/parse_url) to override the specific part:

```
<?php
$arr = parse_url("http://www.domain.com/something/remove_me/?foo&bar");
$arr['path'] = "/something/";
printf("%s://%s%s?%s", $arr['scheme'], $arr['host'], $arr['path'], $arr['query']);
```